# Remove special characters and replace spaces with "-"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to make a directory that is okay to appear in a URL. I want to ensure that it doesn't contain any special characters and replace any spaces with hyphens.

```
from os.path import join as osjoin
def image_dir(self, filename):
    categorydir = ''.join(e for e in  str(self.title.lower()) if e.isalnum())
    return "category/" + osjoin(categorydir, filename)
```

It's removing special characters however I'd like use `.replace(" ", "-")` to swap out spaces with hyphens

Comment: have you tried using the `.replace()` you posted? that seems legitimate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is probably to use the [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) function which takes any string as input and returns an URL-compatible one, yours is not an URL but it will do the trick, eg:

```py
>>> from django.utils.text import slugify
>>> slugify(' Joel is a slug ')
'joel-is-a-slug'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the [quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) function?

```
import urllib.parse

urlllib.parse.quote(filename.replace(" ", "-"), safe="")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this functions and call *remove_special_chars(s)* to do it:

```
def __is_ascii__(c):
    return (ord(c) < 128)


def remove_special_chars(s):
    output = ''

    for c in s:
        if (c.isalpha() and __is_ascii__(c)) or c == ' ':
            output = output + c
        else:
            if c in string.punctuation:
                output = output + ' '

    output = re.sub(' +', ' ', output)
    output = output.replace(' ', '-')

    return output
```

It will remove each non-ASCII character and each element in *string.punctuation*

**EDIT:**
This function will substitute each element in *string.punctuation* with a '-', if you want you can substitute ' ' with '' in the else statement to merge the two parts of the string before and after the punctuation element.